# select names that is equal to the id of other tables - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables products and categories. For products I have the ff fields:

- id
- pname
- category_id
- date

And for the cateogries id I have:

- id
- name

So using inner join I am trying to select all the names of categories that are equal to the category_id inside the products table.

Here's my take:

```
SELECT
    c.name
FROM
    categories AS c
    INNER JOIN products AS p ON c.id = p.category_id
```

However this one did not work out and it's just sending me an empty array.

Any idea how can I do this? thanks!

Comment: when you have the tables `products` and `categories`...then why you select from `budget_categories` and `transactions` ?? ...but since you get no error, but an empty result list, i assume the table and even the column names are valid/existent, and just no data matches the condition. (Do you select/join the correct/desired table?)

Comment: Your question asks about `Products` and `Categories` - but your SQL is about `budget_categories` and `transactions`. Please reword your question so your terminology is consistent.

Comment: sorry I edited it  now. I pasted the wrong SQL statement for my question. I was copying a lot of things. @xerx593

Comment: Works fine here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6025f2/1 You'll get an empty result if there are no products in any of the categories.

Comment: np, bro...just for debug, do: `select * from prodcuts` and `select * from categories`

Comment: Can a product have a category ID that isn't in the categories table? It's not clear why you need the join, unless you're trying to get the category of a specific product ID.

Comment: Can you post sample contents of the tables?

Comment: @Barmar: I think it really works however instead of returning 1 record, it returns me 10 records with the same name. Just a side note I have 10 names under my categories table. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT` if you want to remove duplicates.

Comment: You're getting 10 records because there are 10 products in that category.

Comment: `INNER JOIN` returns a cross product of all the rows that match the conditions. So if there are 10 products in a category, you get 10 rows.

Comment: is using SELECT DISTINCT the most efficient way to select/return the only one record with same category id without having receive a couple of results? or we can use OUTER join or LEFT INNER JOIN to get exactly just one record? @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want category names, then `exists` or `in` is more appropriate than `join`:

```
SELECT c.name
FROM categories c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products p WHERE c.id = p.category_id);
```

You will not have to worry about eliminating duplicates, unless two categories have the same name.

This is also much more efficient than using `SELECT DISTINCT` on your query, especially if `products` has an index where `category_id` is the first key.